# GeckoFx loaded page grey

Tags: c#, geckofx

I have GeckoFX 45 in my project and use it as a web-scraper and it loads YouTube page and gathers info like title, number of comments, top viewed video, etc...
After I did not use this tool for over a year but all other web is loading when I debug it.
In the browser, I have this code even if I try to comment all, it still cannot load youtube page and it is grayed and we can't see anything.

```
GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = UserAgent
GeckoPreferences.[Default]("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
GeckoPreferences.User("security.warn_viewing_mixed") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("media.navigator.enabled") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("media.navigator.permission.disabled") = True 'False
GeckoPreferences.User("plugin.state.flash") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("browser.xul.error_pages.enabled") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("browser.screen_resolution") = 1
GeckoPreferences.User("dom.max_script_run_time") = 0
GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.ssl") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.ssl_port") = True
GeckoPreferences.[Default]("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and I asked about it on the [BitBucket repository for Geckofx60.64](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/issues/68/only-youtube-not-loading-in-geckofx6064).

Comment: @Peacock i found the way, just change the useragent to the latest ones for example this ua works:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.036
I hope it helps.

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you? Feel free to [upvote/accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the behavior.
If you specify an older or inconsistent string you get either blocked (browser no longer supported page) or the clips greyed out view.

However, if you **specify no UA** or **override it with a proper current UA** string it will work, e.g.

```
GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0";
```